# Compile error CS1647 when opening large aspx file in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, webforms

I am using XML/XSLT to create an aspx page which can grow quite large. Even though the file is successfully created, when the file size approaches 300K, the error: “CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile” is issued when opening the file in a browser (tried both IE and Chrome). No other useful information is shown on the failed .NET error page.

My development environment is VS 2012 Express for Web on a Win7 x64 laptop.

Since this problem does not occur during the execution of the program, I am at a loss as to how to approach solving this problem. Can anyone suggest a strategy or work around to this issue?

**EDIT**

The C# code used to create the aspx page is

```
// load the xml file
XmlDocument reportDetails = new XmlDocument();
reportDetails.Load(ReportDetailsPath);
//setup the xslt transform
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(XlsRptPath);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xslt.Transform(ReportDetails, null, sw);
//create the aspx file
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(aspxPath))
{
    outfile.Write(sw.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT server-side in your ASP.NET code? Which .NET code do you use exactly to run the transformation?

Comment: AFAIR. There is a limitalion for 256MB maximum stack size for IIS. Are you sure the XSLT processing doesn't exceed this limit?

Comment: How can I determine if it exceeds 256MB? The resultant aspx file is about 300K. By the time the error occurs, the xslt transform is long gone and the file contains mostly html.

Comment: After your aspx file is written it wll be subject to [dynamic compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms366723.aspx). In the `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder you'll find your parsed and final .cs file. That file expose [the similar issue described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960305/work-around-for-c-sharp-codedom-causing-stack-overflow-cs1647-in-csc-exe).

Comment: This happens if number of line wraps is too many (335440 is max for x64, 926240 is max for x86) - make sure you post-process output of xslt or format it accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960305/work-around-for-c-sharp-codedom-causing-stack-overflow-cs1647-in-csc-exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for not posting my solution sooner, but I was too stressed at the time to do so. Better late than never I guess.

Instead of trying to create a complete aspx web page for each associated xml file, I created a stub and applied the xslt transform at run-time from within an associated Site.Master. The stub's **MasterPageFile** property is set to this Site.Master. This approach does sacrifice some performance, but it works for any size web page. Here is an example of the outputted  [webpage](http://top-60.bunkerhill.com/Top-60-austin-beauty-salons).

**Example aspx stub file:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Top Austin Beauty Salons List" MetaDescription="List of best Google-ranked Austin beauty salon" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Site.Master Page_Load:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vp =  Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;
        if (vp.ToLower().EndsWith("default.aspx") || vp.ToLower().EndsWith("webform2.aspx")) return; // ignore some aspx files used for ohter reasons
        string xmlPath = Page.MapPath(vp.Substring(0, vp.LastIndexOf(".")) + @".xml");
        string xslPath = Page.MapPath("mainpage.xslt");
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlPath);
        XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
        argsList.AddParam("xmlPath", "", xmlPath);

        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(xslPath);
        // Execute the transform and output the results to a string writer.
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        xslt.Transform(xmlDoc, argsList, sw);
        content.InnerHtml = sw.ToString(); // add the generated html to the associated stub aspx content section
    }
```

Comment: apparently, the XSLT created pure HTML, there was no need for aspx reprocessing. Indeed, if no code is generated, this is an excellent solution. It also begs the question why a pure HTML aspx file cannot be compiled in ASP.NET. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I was kinda surprised it worked too. Perhaps this solution raises more questions than answers.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, and largely answered in the comments. But for the sake of completeness, let's answer it ;). Your issue is not with XSLT itself, but with the generated file which [hits the 300k boundary of maximum expression size in C#](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785173/got-error-cs1647-an-expression-is-too-long-or-complex-to-compile-in-vs2012). There are a couple of things you can do:

- Make the generated code below 300k (but this might not be possible in your case)
- Take any string constants in the generated code and place them in a
  resource file. The format of such resource files is XML and you can
  auto-generate it, just make sure the IDs in the resource match the
  IDs you use in the generated ASPX
- Place part of the generated code in a code-behind file. An ASPX is
  parsed as one expression, but the code-behind is not. This is a
  matter of structuring the generated code.
- Split the ASPX in multiple pages, if your design allows this. You can
  recombine them with iframes.
- Split the ASPX file in multiple ASCX controls. This is perhaps the
  most natural thing to do. Each ASCX control can be referenced/added
  to the ASPX file. Each ASCX control should not exceed the 300k limit.
- If there is a lot of generated CSS that blows up the size, place it
  in a separate CSS file.
- If there are a lot of long absolute paths in image references and the 
  like, you can collapse them and make the references relative, i.e. by 
  using [`<base>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp), which may save you some space.
- If the error is caused by actual large (constant) expressions, consider the 
  [hints in the answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960305/work-around-for-c-sharp-codedom-causing-stack-overflow-cs1647-in-csc-exe) for a resolution.

Comment: Thanks Abel. I am sure some developers will find your answer quite useful. I decided to use a a different approach and have (finally) posted my solution to this interesting issue.