# VS2012- Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a website in VS2010 with XP OS & it's working fine. Now I upgraded my PC to Win-7 with VS2012, whenever I try to run the same website in VS2012 it's throwing following error.

Compiler Error Message: CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File:    Line: 0

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" ..................................etc

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929

for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

fatal error CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

I need a help to complete this project in VS2012. Thanks in advance

Comment: was your xp 64bit and windows 7 32 bit?

Comment: What is target framwork of your project?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets. this is my old XP machine config & im unable to see any bit config..    Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_qfe.120821-1630)

Comment: @kostasch. i need to run this website with FW 4.5

Comment: Do you have a program files(x86) folder on your xp?

Comment: I suppose the project is on .net 4.5 and you have installed .net 4.5 on your pc.

Comment: @kostasch.yes but i have changed my web config but it's showing the same msg....

Comment: @MichaelDibbets.. no I have nly program files folder in my old machine

Comment: @MichaelDibbets & kostas..  my old webconfig file is...<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
  
 </system.web>
 <connectionStrings>
  
  <add name="GeoAppDevConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=GeoAppDev;User ID=sa;Password=sql2012"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: & I have modified the file as follows.... <configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
  
 </system.web>
 <connectionStrings>
  
  <add name="GeoAppDevConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=GeoAppDev;User ID=sa;Password=sql2012"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not gone very deep. This may be Microsoft's memory management problem. You can obtain the output by separating code blocks. Refer to the following
[Getting "An expression is too long or complex to compile" when using c# target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787095/getting-an-expression-is-too-long-or-complex-to-compile-when-using-c-sharp-tar) and

[Work-around for C# CodeDom causing stack-overflow (CS1647) in csc.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960305/work-around-for-c-sharp-codedom-causing-stack-overflow-cs1647-in-csc-exe)